# Django can't find table on EC2

Tags: python, django

I'm in a weird situation where the Django Admin is able to view and perform CRUD operations on the DB.

If I create a `venue` in the Admin, I can access the `name` of the venue in one of my database calls. However, if I want full details, i've written another view to get details. Here I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /getVenue/
(1146, "Table 'app_rest.venuemanagement_venue' doesn't exist")
```

When I check `python manage.py dbshell`, I can see the tables but as follows:

```
VenueManagement_venue
```

Is it because of the case of the table name that I can't find the table? How do I fix this?

Comment: I think it is related to the case, I have seen similar errors recently. Try to have the same case everywhere

Comment: @Paco, but isn't this a Django DB connector issue? How do I solve this from my end?

Comment: I know that my colleague did an `ALTER TABLE` to rename it, but this is probably not the best option. I can't help more than that :-/